# How to Load CSS asynchronous in NextJS

Tags: next.js

I want my global CSS file to load asynchronous, i.e without render-blocking. My page is waiting for FCP until it gets CSS loaded.
So, How can I achieve this in next js.

What I am getting :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/css/eb4e3a560474a24ae771.css" data-n-g="">
```

What is Expected :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/css/eb4e3a560474a24ae771.css" data-n-g="" media="all" onload="this.media='all'">
```

Comment: Did you find any solution? I tried many approaches like preload, preconnect and `this.media='all'`, but the css loaded but never change the text to google Lato font. When I put it normal, it works, but it blocks rendering. Should we put them at the bottom page?

Answer (score 0):

NextJS documentation on Font Optimization https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/font-optimization says that they transform provided `<link>` to preconnect with added style:

```
// Before
<link
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter&display=optional"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>

// After
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
<style data-href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter&display=optional">
  @font-face{font-family:'Inter';font-style:normal...
</style>
```

Now, you just need to adapt GET parameter `display=[value]` to adapt to `font-display` standard https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-display. The list is:

```
/* Keyword values */
font-display: auto;
font-display: block;
font-display: swap;
font-display: fallback;
font-display: optional;
```

Many are for mostly non-blocking (small block) display. All of them are explained in the Mozilla link, but the one I prefer, `font-display: swap` that gives extremely small block for font to load and if not in time, infinite swap period to change the font everywhere when it's loaded:

> **swap**
> Gives the font face an extremely small block period and an
> infinite swap period.

> **Font block period**
> If the font face is not loaded, any element
> attempting to use it must render an invisible fallback font face. If
> the font face successfully loads during this period, it is used
> normally.
>
> **Font swap period**
> If the font face is not loaded, any element
> attempting to use it must render a fallback font face. If the font
> face successfully loads during this period, it is used normally.

This way we can chose what fits better for us. If it still blocks a lot, I guess you'll have to put the link at the bottom of page.